# Firebase Cloud Functions Sending Error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to send an error to my iOS Application using Firebase Cloud Functions.

But I don't get any error when I use my url:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
    print(error) // Print nil
}
```

I have tried all these:

```
res.status(400).send("error");
res.status(400).send(New Error("error"));
console.error(new Error('A problem occurred'));
res.render({error:...})
```

Comment: On a side note: **don't force unwrap variables like this**. Use `if let` or `guard let` to check whether the URL is nil.

Comment: This is just an example, but thanks anyway. 

Comment: When you call console.error(), does it show up in the Firebase Console Functions Logs? If not, your function probably fails before the response is sent.

Comment: I have been wondering this myself too

Answer (score 0):

Yea there is no way. The error message you send back like res.status(400).send("error"); is in the body itself. If you look at FIRFunctions.m file, it ignores that as it returns a firebase error message instead "Unimplemented" and "Internal" which are totally unconceptual and misleading messages. Like you get unimplemented error for res.status(400).send("error"). So the bottom line, the iOS SDK doesn't support it. You can to write your own localized error messages in your client side which is actually at the end better.